# how to prevent "directory already exists error" in a makefile when using mkdir

Tags: makefile, directory, exists

I need to generate a directory in my makefile and I would like to not get the "directory already exists error" over and over even though I can easily ignore it.

I mainly use mingw/msys but would like something that works across other shells/systems  too.

I tried this but it didn't work, any ideas?

```
ifeq (,$(findstring $(OBJDIR),$(wildcard $(OBJDIR) )))
-mkdir $(OBJDIR)
endif
```

Answer (score 127, accepted):

On UNIX Just use this:

```
mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)
```

The -p option to mkdir prevents the error message if the directory exists.

Comment: "Generally, stick to the widely-supported (usually posix-specified) options and features of these programs. For example, don't use ‘mkdir -p’, convenient as it may be, because a few systems don't support it at all and with others, it is not safe for parallel execution. "  http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/make/Utilities-in-Makefiles.html

Comment: `-p` doesn't work on Windows, which is presumably what the question is asking about. Not sure how this ever got accepted.

Comment: For Windows, up vote this: https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/1074131/mkdir-and-rm-needs-unix-like-most-pertinent-switches

Comment: @Antimony You probably did something wrong if you're using GNU Make outside of the MinGW shell. Your choice, though.

Answer (score 129):

Looking at [the official make documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types), here is a good way to do it:

```
OBJDIR := objdir
OBJS := $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,foo.o bar.o baz.o)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.c
    $(COMPILE.c) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<

all: $(OBJS)

$(OBJS): | $(OBJDIR)

$(OBJDIR):
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)
```

You should see here the usage of the | pipe operator, defining an order only prerequisite.
Meaning that the `$(OBJDIR)` target should be existent (instead of *more recent*) in order to build the current target.

Note that I used `mkdir -p`. The `-p` flag was added compared to the example of the docs.
See other answers for another alternative.

Comment: @CraigMcQueen: I truly meant _"the `$(OBJDIR)` target should be **existent**"_. Make checks for file presence (and timestamps) to decide if it need to build the target. Hence here, if `$(OBJDIR)` is absent it will build it, so that it is **existent** in order to build the current target `$(OBJS)`, that will be created inside.

Comment: I think I have literally tried every other combination of solving this problem before finding this (I am trying to generate makefiles that are as generic as I can between windows/linux) - this is pretty much the only one I could get working, but it works so well! : )

Answer (score 72):

You can use the test command:

```
test -d $(OBJDIR) || mkdir $(OBJDIR)
```

Comment: This is the preferred way if you need your makefiles to work in both Windows (with gnuwin32 and PowerShell) and POSIX-compliant OS's.

Comment: PROVIDED you have the gnuwin32 CoreUtils package to provide the 'test' utility.

Comment: Way late here, but I'd like to point out that this solution can break when building in parallel (`make -j`) due to a race condition between when the directory is tested for existence and it is created. One job can test that it's not there but before it creates it, another job creates the directory. Then when the first tries to make it, it will fail because the directory already exists. The best solution in this case is to use order only prerequisites as mentioned in @TeKa's answer (which should be the accepted answer).

Comment: @MarcusJ Works on my OS X El Capitan. Which version broke it?

Comment: @C0deH4cker - Forgive my ignorance... Which answer is TeKa? I think TeKa changed his/her name since you made the comment.

Answer (score 19):

Here is a trick I use with GNU make for creating compiler-output directories. First define this rule:

```
  %/.d:
          mkdir -p $(@D)
          touch $@
```

Then make all files that go into the directory dependent on the .d file in that directory:

```
 obj/%.o: %.c obj/.d
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

Note use of $< instead of $^.

Finally prevent the .d files from being removed automatically:

```
 .PRECIOUS: %/.d
```

Skipping the .d file, and depending directly on the directory, will not work, as the directory modification time is updated every time a file is written in that directory, which would force rebuild at every invocation of make.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I was trying to get something like this to work. I don't want "test -d foo || mkdir foo" on several goals, since then using "make -j2" will test them at the same time, both tests giving false, and then two processes will try to mkdir, the last of them failing.

Answer (score 13):

If having the directory already exist is not a problem for you, you could just redirect stderr for that command, getting rid of the error message:

```
-mkdir $(OBJDIR) 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: This has the advantage of working on Windows, too.  Don't forget the '-' in front of the command so make doesn't bail.

Answer (score 11):

Inside your makefile:

```
target:
    if test -d dir; then echo "hello world!"; else mkdir dir; fi
```

Answer (score 10):

On Windows

```
if not exist "$(OBJDIR)" mkdir $(OBJDIR)
```

On Unix | Linux

```
if [ ! -d "$(OBJDIR)" ]; then mkdir $(OBJDIR); fi
```

Comment: This one for Windows.

Comment: `/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "then")
`

Comment: The first version is for Windows, the second option works on Linux as @checksum said

Comment: The first, Windows, version is not atomic so it does not work when another process (e.g. a rule in parallel mode) creates the directory between the "not exist" and "mkdir".

Answer (score 7):

```
ifeq "$(wildcard $(MY_DIRNAME) )" ""
  -mkdir $(MY_DIRNAME)
endif
```

Comment: This works well for mingw's make without requiring extra tools.

Answer (score 6):

```
$(OBJDIR):
    mkdir $@
```

Which also works for multiple directories, e.g..

```
OBJDIRS := $(sort $(dir $(OBJECTS)))

$(OBJDIRS):
    mkdir $@
```

Adding `$(OBJDIR)` as the first target works well.

Answer (score 3):

It works under mingw32/msys/cygwin/linux

```
ifeq "$(wildcard .dep)" ""
-include $(shell mkdir .dep) $(wildcard .dep/*)
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

A little simpler than Lars' answer:

```
something_needs_directory_xxx : xxx/..
```

and generic rule:

```
%/.. : ;@mkdir -p $(@D)
```

No touch-files to clean up or make .PRECIOUS :-)

If you want to see another little generic gmake trick, or if you're interested in non-recursive make with minimal scaffolding, you might care to check out [Two more cheap gmake tricks](https://mischasan.wordpress.com/2012/07/05/two-more-cheap-gmake-tricks-creating-directories-and-printing-variables/) and the other make-related posts in that blog.

Answer (score 0):

If you explicitly ignore the return code and dump the error stream then your make will ignore the error if it occurs:

```
mkdir 2>/dev/null || true
```

This should not cause a race hazard in a parallel make - but I haven't tested it to be sure.