# A Concise Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am doing some Makefile refactoring and trying to figure out the most concise way to implement a Makefile that does the following:

1. Has one variable that has all the source files listed (can be both C and C++ files)
2. All object files are generated in OBJ_DIR
3. The object directory is created if it does not exist

Here is what I have so far:

```
...

OBJ_DIR = obj/
BIN_DIR = bin/
PROGRAM = program

SRCS = test1.cpp test2.c

OBJS  = $(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR), \
        $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o,  \
        $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(SRCS))))

$(BIN_DIR)$(PROGRAM) : $(OBJS)
    $(CREATE_OUT_DIR)
    $(LINK)

$(OBJ_DIR)%.o : %.c
    $(CREATE_OBJ_DIR)
    $(CCOMPILE)

$(OBJ_DIR)%.o : %.cpp
    $(CREATE_OBJ_DIR)
    $(CPPCOMPILE)

...
```

I'd like to eliminate the call to $(CREATE_OBJ_DIR) for every .o compile. Anyone know how to do this? I tried adding this, but then it would not build the object files:

```
$(OBJS): | $(OBJ_DIR)

$(OBJ_DIR):
    $(CREATE_OBJ_DIR)
```

Comment: I see issues with this design. How do you account for header dependencies ? I usually write makefiles with something like `src = $(shell find ./ --name "*.cpp")` and use GCC `-M` switches to have dependancies handled for me. This way, I have a short reusable makefile for all my projects. As to your actual problem, why not create the `obj` directory beforehand ?

Comment: Not exactly an answer but have you already looked at alternatives to `Makefile` ? `SConstruct` comes to my mind (and is great) but there is a lot of other tools that deals with those kind of problems very well.

Comment: @Alexandre: I was also going to look into header dependencies. Do you have a good example as to how to do this?

Comment: a decent starting point is mad-scientist.net/make/autodep.html and the GCC options you may want to investigate are variants of `-M`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already seem to have solved your first point: Have them all in one variable (I shouldn't think you actually need to to separate them into TEMP1 and TEMP2 like you have, just have different build rules)

For the second point, you can tell the compiler where to output the object files (for g++ its like this:

```
g++ -c MySourceFile.cpp -o obj/MySourceFile.o
```

The make rule for this would look like:

```
obj/%.o: %.cpp
    g++ -c $*.cpp -o obj/$*.o
```

And your third point is also easily solved, as you can have a build rule for it (Just put the directory name in the dependency list for the target, before all of the objects are listed), and the build rule would look like this

```
obj:
    mkdir obj
```

Edit: or following your code examples:

```
$(BIN_DIR)$(PROGRAM) : $(BIN_DIR) $(OBJS) 
$(LINK)

$(BIN_DIR):
    $(CREATE_OUT_DIR)
```

Comment: Directory dependency should be order-only dependency.

Comment: I compressed the object file list generation into one command. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

As for your 3rd point: This question has [been asked here before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/99132/how-to-check-if-a-directory-exists-in-a-makefile). Unfortunately there is no really good answer for this, and you need to find the least ugly hack from the answer. Personally, I vote for the marker file solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do:

```
$(OBJ_LOC)/%.o: $(SRC_LOC)/%.c
    @[ -d $(OBJ_LOC) ] || mkdir -p $(OBJ_LOC)
    g++ ...
```

But, I am looking at these other answers with great interest.