# Test whether a directory exists inside a makefile

Tags: bash, makefile

In his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59839/671013) @Grundlefleck explains how to check whether a directory exists or not. I tried some to use this inside a `makefile` as follow:

```
foo.bak: foo.bar
    echo "foo"
    if [ -d "~/Dropbox" ]; then
        echo "Dir exists"
    fi
```

Running `make foo.bak` (given that `foo.bar` exists) yields the following error:

```
echo "foo"
foo
if [ -d "~/Dropbox" ]; then
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
make: *** [foo.bak] Error 2
```

The workaround I made was to have a standalone bash script where the test is implemented and I called the script from the `makefile`. This, however, sounds very cumbersome. Is there a nicer way to check whether a directory exists from within a `makefile`?

Comment: You can try something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/99188/1620573

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Make commands, if a shell command, must be in one line, or be on multiple lines using a backslash for line extension. So, this approach will work:

```
foo.bak: foo.bar
    echo "foo"
    if [ -d "~/Dropbox" ]; then echo "Dir exists"; fi
```

Or

```
foo.bak: foo.bar
    echo "foo"
    if [ -d "~/Dropbox" ]; then \
        echo "Dir exists"; \
    fi
```

Comment: It looks like the issue is that everything needs to be on one line. Is that true?

Comment: @PatrickCollins individual commands can be on separate lines. For example `echo "foo" followed by `mv bar bah` can be commands on separate lines. The shell, though, sees the `if` expression through to the `fi` as a single command, so it must be on one line, or have "escaped" (`\`) line breaks. As you can see in the answer, `echo "foo"` can be on a separate line before the `if` expression as it's a separate command.

Comment: @PatrickCollins To make the long answer short, yes.  Each line is ran it it's own shell, so you can't put the test on one line and the block below it, as the block will be in a different shell.  This can formatted across multiple lines with the line-continuation character '\' which again, effectively puts it all on one line.

Comment: ; is must, this is okay:     if [ -d ${BOOTSTRAPDIR} ]; then \
        echo "Found ${BOOTSTRAPDIR}"; \
    else    \
        echo "Do not find ${BOOTSTRAPDIR}"; \
    fi

Comment: Does a simple dependency on the right side of the `:` written `~/Dropbox/.` could work? A `makefile` is a file tester in the first place.

Comment: @Sandburg my answer is 10 years old now. I think you're correct. I'm sure there are multiple good ways to address the original question.

Answer (score 69):

This approach functions with minimal echos:

```
.PHONY: all
all:
ifneq ($(wildcard ~/Dropbox/.*),)
        @echo "Found ~/Dropbox."
else
        @echo "Did not find ~/Dropbox."
endif
```

Comment: `$(wildcard ~/Dropbox/.)` is enough. The wildcard character is not necessary in this use case

Comment: For me it actually didn't work until I removed the * wildcard character, for some reason.

Comment: in my case:

```Makefile
ifneq "$(wildcard path/$(var)/*)" ""
 @echo "dir already exists"
else
 @echo "do something"
endif
```

Answer (score 53):

**Act upon the absence of a directory**

If you only need to know if a directory does not exist and want to act upon that by for example creating it, you can use ordinary Makefile targets:

```
directory = ~/Dropbox

all: | $(directory)
    @echo "Continuation regardless of existence of ~/Dropbox"

$(directory):
    @echo "Folder $(directory) does not exist"
    mkdir -p $@

.PHONY: all
```

Remarks:

- The `|` indicates that make shouldn't care about the timestamp (it's an [order-only-prerequisite](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html)).
- Rather than write `mkdir -p $@`, you can write `false` to exit, or solve your case differently.

If you also need to run a particular series of instructions upon the **existence** of a directory, you cannot use the above. In other words, it is equivalent to:

```
if [ ! -d "~/Dropbox" ]; then
    echo "The ~/Dropbox folder does not exist"
fi
```

There is no `else` statement.

**Act upon the presence of a directory**

If you want the opposite if-statement this is also possible:

```
directory = $(wildcard ~/Dropbox)

all: | $(directory)
    @echo "Continuation regardless of existence of ~/Dropbox"

$(directory):
    @echo "Folder $(directory) exists"

.PHONY: all $(directory)
```

This is equivalent to:

```
if [ -d "~/Dropbox" ]; then
    echo "The ~/Dropbox folder does exist"
fi
```

Again, there is no `else` statement.

**Act upon both the presence and the absence of a directory**

This becomes a bit more cumbersome, but in the end gives you nice targets for both cases:

```
directory = ~/Dropbox
dir_target = $(directory)-$(wildcard $(directory))
dir_present = $(directory)-$(directory)
dir_absent = $(directory)-

all: | $(dir_target)
    @echo "Continuation regardless of existence of ~/Dropbox"

$(dir_present):
    @echo "Folder $(directory) exists"

$(dir_absent):
    @echo "Folder $(directory) does not exist"

.PHONY: all
```

This is equivalent to:

```
if [ -d "~/Dropbox" ]; then
    echo "The ~/Dropbox folder does exist"
else
    echo "The ~/Dropbox folder does not exist"
fi
```

Naturally, the wildcard expansion might be slower than an if-else-statement. However, the third case is probably quite rare and is just added for completeness.

Comment: Thanks for wonderful codes! However, what if I can do with multiple $(directories)?

Comment: @Seung-WooLee That would take it yet another step. :-) In that case I would argue for using the shell itself with a .ONESHELL special target for readability.

Comment: Is the test possible on the directory itself (like in your example) or should I test `~/Dropbox/.` for a better result?

Answer (score 18):

Try this:

```
.PHONY: all
something:
    echo "hi"
all:
    test -d "Documents" && something
```

This will execute the commands under `something` only if `Documents` exists.

In order to address the [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20763629/test-whether-a-directory-exists-inside-a-makefile/20763801#comment31118667_20763629) noted in the comments, you can make a variable like this:

```
PATH_TEST = ~/SomeDirectory

test -d $(PATH_TEST) && something
```

Answer (score 16):

I had a case where I wanted to define a variable based on the test whether a directory exists or not at the *top-most level* of the `Makefile` where the approaches described above don't work. I found [here](http://pastebin.com/gcetwyft) a nice solution which can be used like this:

```
MY_DIRNAME=../External
ifneq "$(wildcard $(MY_DIRNAME) )" ""
  # if directory MY_DIRNAME exists:
  INCLUDES += -I../External
else
  # if it doesn't:
  INCLUDES += -I$(HOME)/Code/External
endif
```

This will modify the variable `INCLUDES` based on whether the directory stored in `MY_DIRNAME` exists or not.

(Motivation: In my case this variable would be used in another `Makefile` included later by the first:

```
include $(SFRAME_DIR)/Makefile.common
```

I wanted to have the same `Makefile` work in two different environments in a simple way.)

Answer (score 5):

There is a very different answer that allows you to use your `if` statements as you envisioned them in one shell:

```
.ONESHELL:
foo.bak: foo.bar
    echo "foo"
    if [ -d "~/Dropbox" ]; then
        echo "Dir exists"
    fi
```

Note that the only difference is the ONESHELL [special target](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/One-Shell.html).

Answer (score 1):

I use the following to detect if a file or a directory exists and act upon it :

```
$(if $(filter expected,$(wildcard *)), the expected file exists)
```

With your request :

```
.PHONY: ~/Dropbox

~/Dropbox:
    echo "Dir exists"

foo.bak: foo.bar | $(if $(filter ~/Dropbox,$(wildcard ~/*)), the expected file exists)
```

Which can further be simplify :

```
foo.bak: foo.bar | $(wildcard ~/Dropbox)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this way is looking simpler and allows for advanced conditions:

```
ifeq ($(shell test -d MYDIR && echo 1 || echo 0), 1)
     ...
endif
```