# Makefile check if folder and/or file exists

Tags: makefile

I have the following Makefile:

```Makefile
build: clean
    ${GOPATH}/bin/dep ensure
    env GOOS=linux go build -o ./bin/status ./lib/status/main.go
    elm-app build

init:
    ${GOPATH}/bin/dep init -v

test:
    env GOOS=linux go test -v ./lib/status

strip:
    strip ./bin/status

clean:
    if [ -f ./bin/status ]; then
        rm -f ./bin/status
    fi
```

but I get

```text
if [ -f ./bin/status ]; then
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: end of file unexpected
Makefile:16: recipe for target 'clean' failed
make: *** [clean] Error 2
```

what am i missing?

any advice is much appreciated

Comment: easier solution: just `rm -f ./bin/status`

option `-f` ignore nonexistent files, check man for _rm_

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Test whether a directory exists inside a makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20763629/test-whether-a-directory-exists-inside-a-makefile)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Each line of a makefile is run in a separate shell.  This means your rule here:

```Makefile
clean:
        if [ -f ./bin/status ]; then
            rm -f ./bin/status
        fi
```

actually runs the following commands:

```Makefile
/bin/sh -c "if [ -f ./bin/status ]; then"
/bin/sh -c "rm -f ./bin/status"
/bin/sh -c "fi"
```

You can see why you get this message.  To ensure that all lines are send into a single shell you need to use backslashes to continue the lines like this:

```Makefile
clean:
        if [ -f ./bin/status ]; then \
            rm -f ./bin/status; \
        fi
```

Note this means you also need a semicolon after the `rm` command so separate it from the ending `fi`.

Now you get a shell invocation like this:

```sh
/bin/sh -c "if [ -f ./bin/status ]; then \
        rm -f ./bin/status; \
    fi"
```

Comment: This explained so much. Thanks a lot buddy! I solved it by adding it as a one-liner. Just wanted to add that this is possible too.

Comment: For a one-liner, this way of writing a condition might be useful: `[ -f ./bin/status ] && rm -f ./bin/status`

Comment: IMO there's no real point in writing this.  If you use `rm -f` it won't fail if the file doesn't exist, so there's no practical difference between `[ -f ./bin/status ] && rm -f ./bin/status` and just writing `rm -f ./bin/status` by itself.  This answer was more about why the original didn't work, than the best way to write it :)

Comment: Actually there is one BIG difference.  In fact your change is not right.  The problem with your formulation is that `[ -f ./bin/status ] && rm -f ./bin/status` will exit with an error code if `./bin/status` does not exist.  That error code will lead make to believe the recipe failed, and it will fail the make.  In general it's usually wrong to use `&&` shortcuts in make recipes for this reason.  You can use `||` though: rewrite as `[ ! -f ./bin/status ] || rm -f ./bin/status` and it will work.  But again, it seems useless when just `rm -f ./bin/status` does the same thing, with less effort.