# Depend on subdirectory creation in makefile rule

Tags: makefile, directory, dependencies, subdirectory

I have a project with sources in the `src/` directory and its subdirectories (e.g. `src/foo/` and `src/bar/`), and the objects in the `obj` directory and the matching subdirectories (e.g. `obj/foo/` and `obj/bar/`).

I use the following (smimplified) `Makefile`:

```
SOURCES=$(shell find src/ -type f -name '*.c')
OBJECTS=$(patsubst src/%.c,obj/%.o,$(SOURCES))

all: $(OBJECTS)

obj/%.o: src/%.c
    gcc -c $< -o $@
```

### The problem

The problem is that if `obj/` or one of its subdirectories doesn't exist, I get the following  error:

```
Fatal error: can't create obj/foo/f1.o: No such file or directory
```

*How can I tell make that `%.o` files depend on the creation of their containing directory?*

### What I tried

[One solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6170280) when there are no subdirectories is to use "order only prerequisites":

```
$(OBJECTS): | obj

obj:
    mkdir $@
```

But that fixes the problem only with `obj/`, but not `obj/foo` and `obj/bar/`. I thought about using [`$(@D)`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables), but I don't know how to get all this together.

I have also used hidden marker files in each directory, but that's just a hack, and I have also put a `mkdir -p` just before the GCC command but that also feels hacky. I'd rather avoid using recursive makefiles, if that were a potential solution.

### Minimal example

To create a minimal project similar to mine you can run:

```
mkdir /tmp/makefile-test
cd /tmp/makefile-test
mkdir src/ src/foo/ src/bar/
echo "int main() { return 0; }" > src/main.c
touch src/foo/f1.c src/bar/b1.c src/bar/b2.c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you consider adding `mkdir -p` before each compiler operation to be "hacky"; that's probably what I'd do.  However, you can also do it like this if you don't mind all the directories created all the time:

First, you should use `:=` for assigning shell variables, not `=`.  The former is *far* more efficient.  Second, once you have a list of filenames it's easy to compute the list of directories.  Try this:

```
SOURCES := $(shell find src/ -type f -name '*.c')
OBJECTS := $(patsubst src/%.c,obj/%.o,$(SOURCES))

# Compute the obj directories
OBJDIRS := $(sort $(dir $(OBJECTS))

# Create all the obj directories
__dummy := $(shell mkdir -p $(OBJDIRS))
```

If you really want to have the directory created only when the object is about to be, then you'll have to use second expansion (not tested):

```
SOURCES := $(shell find src/ -type f -name '*.c')
OBJECTS := $(patsubst src/%.c,obj/%.o,$(SOURCES))

# Compute the obj directories
OBJDIRS := $(sort $(dir $(OBJECTS))

.SECONDEXPANSION:

obj/%.o : src/%.c | $$(@D)
        $(CC) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJDIRS):
        mkdir -p $@
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it this way:

```
SOURCES=$(shell find src -type f -name '*.c')  # corrected small error

...

obj/%.o: src/%.c
    if [ ! -d $(dir $@) ]; then mkdir -p $(dir $@); fi
    gcc -c $< -o $@
```

Comment: Thanks, I used `$(shell dirname $@)`, but `$(dir $@)` is much cleaner. Otherwise, that's roughly equivalent to what I was doing already (`mkdir -p` ignores creation of already existing directories, so the `if` is redundant). Now I think about it, `$(@D)` is even better, although more cryptic.