# Create directory only once when running makefile in parallel

Tags: makefile, bioinformatics, pipeline, fastq

I'm using make to write a pipeline for biological data analysis. My project directory is:

```
PROJECT
 - DATA
  - SAMPLEA
   - A1.FASTQ A2.FASTQ
  - SAMPLEB
   - B1.FASTQ B2.FASTQ
 - RESULTS
 - SRC
  - makefile
```

My current makefile uses a wildcard to list the directory of all .FASTQ files in the DATA directory. Using pattern rules each .FASTQ file then goes through a series of recipes with the final output file written to the RESULTS directory. Instead, I would like to create a directory for each SAMPLE where the final output file is written:

```
PROJECT/RESULTS/SAMPLEA/A1.out
PROJECT/RESULTS/SAMPLEA/A2.out
PROJECT/RESULTS/SAMPLEB/B1.out
PROJECT/RESULTS/SAMPLEB/B2.out
```

I can do this by having the first recipe make the directory, however this throws an error when the second of the FASTQ files from the same SAMPLE also tries to create the directory. A few posts on stack overflow suggest using the -p flag on mkdir to ignore errors, however this apparently causes problems when I run the makefile in parallel using the -j flag. I thought about forcing a shell script at the start of the makefile to run, to check if the results directories are present, and if not then it should create them, but I'd like to try and solve this issue using just make.

Comment: What problems does using `-p` cause with using `-j`? It shouldn't cause any that I can think of.

Comment: @EtanReisner According to a fellow stack overflow user it will cause problems (although they haven't listed exactly what it is), see greg.kindel's comment in this related question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/99132/how-to-prevent-directory-already-exists-error-in-a-makefile-when-using-mkdir)

Comment: Ah, yes, that's from the manual and is almost certainly correct on some (likely obscure) system somewhere. If you have any expectation that your project will need to be made on such a system you are free to listen to that (mostly reasonable) advice. If you don't you can ignore it. If you do want to listen to it then just manually test for the directory existing before creating it in the recipe for it.

Comment: I guess I can just put a conditional in the recipe which is supposed to create the directory? Or should I test / create the directory in a shell script at the start before building the targets? Would there be any difference?

Comment: Yes, just in the recipe where you would have used `mkdir -p`. As, apparently, Solaris 10 is still race-y with `mkdir -p`.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try now and report back if I encounter any more problems.

Comment: @EtanReisner Just a thought, won't this cause a race condition if the first job creates the directory just after the second job checks and finds it is not present?

Comment: In theory, yes. That's actually the problem with `-p` in the race-y versions from what I read in the autoconf manual. Unfortunately I don't think you can really avoid that without pre-creating it without a `mkdir` that isn't broken (other than by just ignoring failures from `mkdir` in the first place in which case you don't need the existence check at all, just `-mkdir $@` or whatever).

Comment: +1 for using something like: `
    A1.out : A1.fastq
        mkdir -p $(dir $@) && dosomething -o $@ $<`

Comment: @Pierre I'm not sure what advantages this has, as the first condition will always be successful given the -p flag? It doesn't avoid the problems with race conditions discussed above, does it?

Comment: I've been running such Makefile-based pipelines for NGS for a few years (e.g:  https://github.com/lindenb/ngsxml ) using a SGE-based cluster but I've never met that problem. And anyway, if it would fail, you'd just have to re-run the make. + Run it with option '-k'

Comment: @Pierre I understand, thank you for the advice. As an aside, I only became interested in learning and using make for building pipelines after your recommendation in various BioStars posts, so kudos!

Answer (score 0):

Create directory before executing rule.

```
DATADIR := $(shell cd DATA; find * -type d)

create_results_dir:= $(shell for i in $(DATADIR); \
    do test -d DATA/$$i && mkdir -p RESULTS/$$i; \
    done)

all:
    @echo do something.
```